# Dynamic Array C

Tags: c

I am trying to solve the Dynamic Array problem of Hackerrank in C. I tried so many ways but all in vain. The best I could do is to clear 4 test cases. I am getting a segmentation error. Please help me find where am I doing wrong. It will be really helpful.

Question Link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array/problem

We are supposed to complete the function. So here is my attempt:

```
int *dynamicArray(int n, int queries_rows, int queries_columns, int **queries, 
                  int *result_count) {
    *result_count = 0;
    int *result = (int *)malloc(queries_rows * sizeof(int));
    int i = 0, j = 0, y, x;
    int lastAnswer = 0;
    int **arr = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    int *size = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        size[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < queries_rows; i++) {
        x = queries[i][1];
        y = queries[i][2];
        if (queries[i][0] == 1) {
            size[(x ^ lastAnswer) % n]++;
            arr[(x ^ lastAnswer) % n][size[(x ^ lastAnswer) % n] - 1] = y;
        } else {
            lastAnswer = arr[(x ^ lastAnswer) % n][y % size[(x ^ lastAnswer) % n]];
            printf("%d\n", lastAnswer);
            (*result_count)++;
            result[(*result_count) - 1] = lastAnswer;
        }
    }
    result = (int *)realloc(result, (*result_count) * sizeof(int));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Actually, as of now I don't know debugging using a debugger.

Comment: Today's the perfect day to learn!

Comment: Okay. I will learn. Thank You.

Comment: All the code provided at that link is naively written. Since they are apparently concerned with performance, those who made that site should read [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: `queries` is supposed to be *string queries[q]: an array of query strings*. Are you sure about the function prototype?

Comment: How do you know all the subarrays in `arr` will be at most `n` items?  Could it be you need to reallocate them occasionally when appending values?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is a little too complicated: you should use an intermediary variable `idx` as specified in the problem statement:

> Create a 2-dimensional array *arr*, of *n* empty arrays. All arrays are zero indexed.
> Create an integer *lastAnswer*, and initialize it to *0*.
> There are  types of queries:
> Query: *1* *x* *y*
> Find the list within *arr* at index *idx = (x ^ lastAnswer) % n*.
> Append the integer *y* to the *arr[idx]*.
> Query: *2* *x* *y*
> Find the list within *arr* at index *idx = (x ^ lastAnswer) % n*.
> Find the value of element *y % size(arr[idx])* where *size* is the number of elements in *arr[idx]*, Assign the value to *lastAnswer*.
> Print the new value of *lastAnswer* on a new line.

Assuming the function prototype is correct, here is a simpler version:

```
int *dynamicArray(int n, int queries_rows, int queries_columns, int **queries, 
                  int *result_count) {
    int **arr = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    int *size = (int *)calloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int *result = (int *)malloc(queries_rows * sizeof(int));
    int i, j;
    int count = 0;
    int lastAnswer = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < queries_rows; i++) {
        int x = queries[i][1];
        int y = queries[i][2];
        int idx = (x ^ lastAnswer) % n;
        if (queries[i][0] == 1) {
            arr[idx][size[idx]++] = y;
        } else {
            lastAnswer = arr[idx][y % size[idx]];
            printf("%d\n", lastAnswer);
            result[count++] = lastAnswer;
        }
    }
    *result_count = count;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
    free(size);    
    
    return (int *)realloc(result, count * sizeof(int));
}
```

The problem with this implementation is the size of the lists in the array `arr` may grow larger than `n`. You should therefore reallocate them as you append values.

Here is a modified version:

```
int *append_list(int **list, int size, int value) {
    *list = realloc(*list, (size + 1) * sizeof(int));
    (*list)[size] = value;
    return p;
}

int *dynamicArray(int n, int queries_rows, int queries_columns, int **queries, 
                  int *result_count) {
    int **arr = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
    int *size = (int *)calloc(n * sizeof(int)); // initializes to 0
    int *result = NULL;
    int i, j;
    int count = 0;
    int lastAnswer = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = NULL;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < queries_rows; i++) {
        int x = queries[i][1];
        int y = queries[i][2];
        int idx = (x ^ lastAnswer) % n;
        if (queries[i][0] == 1) {
            append_list(&arr[idx], size[idx]++, y);
        } else {
            lastAnswer = arr[idx][y % size[idx]];
            printf("%d\n", lastAnswer);
            append_list(&result, count++, lastAnswer);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
    free(size);    
    
    *result_count = count;
    return result;
}
```